# How can i generate the response file for my binary installable?

Tags: linux, shell

I have the binary file to install a component when i am running using ./filename.bin it comes into console mode and asks for language selection and directory selection and all , i tried ./filename.bin -r path/response.properties, help me if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said that you have already tried using ./filename.bin -r path/response.properties and still it does not work then , do one thing go for the console mode while creating the response file like :-

> ./filename.bin -i console -r path/response.properties

then install what you are installing, the response file will capture that.

And to use that later you can just include tat while running your bin file to take the input from response file.